# Speed of using mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

My question is: is it faster to do an operation for every item in an array even if it doesn't require it or to check if it requires it first.

Example: I have a loop that is set up like this [metacode]

```
foreach($array as $varkey => $varvalue){
    if(!is_array($varkey)) $varvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($varvalue); 
}
```

One of my coworkers believes that we should only use the mysql_real_escape_string function is the $varvalue has an apostrophe in it. That would require the use of a `strstr()` or `preg_match()` to see if an apostrophe was present before using mysql_real_escape_string, like so:

```
foreach($array as $varkey => $varvalue){
    if(!is_array($varkey)){
        if(strstr("'", $varvalue) $varvalue = mysql_real_escape_string($varvalue); 
    }
}
```

Is there any speed/security advantage with going one or the other?

*ps. I know we should probably be using prepared statements with PDO or mysqli_. That's another conversation we need to have internally on another day.*

Comment: apostrophe are NOT the only issue, your co-worker is crazy: `mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a. `

Comment: Would you mind giving me your coworker's database-driven website URL?

Comment: Your co-worker is 100% completely incorrect.

Comment: or his home address, i bet the spare key is under the door-mat

Comment: `I know we should probably be using prepared statements with PDO or mysqli_. That's another conversation we need to have internally on another day.` That is the main conversation you should have done already as well as be deploying it.

Comment: to correctly determine when you need to call the function, you'd need to reproduce all the logic of the function. obviously that's neither robust nor performant.

Comment: Aside from your co-worker's silliness, it's the usual micro-optimisation question. If you want to know, profile the code. Be prepared to waste more time doing this than you'll ever recover in improved performance.

Comment: Even if we assume you will be able to get your `mysql_real_escape_string_only_if_really_needed` function to work correctly, this is still premature optimisation. You should only do micro optimisations when there is a problem and all other options are exhausted.

Comment: @prix I would agree. Working on a 10+ year old code base with millions of lines of codes. Migrating to PDO is going to be a massive undertaking. It needs to happen, sooner rather than later, but it's hard to make a case for that over new features or bug fixes.

Comment: You would lose less time switching to prepared statement with MySQLi/PDO than having all this discussion and trying to create an over protective function that will most likely have bugs against functions used for years. Not to mention you really care about performance to the milliseconds which you would then have to profile every change several times which would again take a lot more time and effort to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mysql_real_escape_string() already searches the string for apostrophes and other characters, and escapes only the characters it is designed to do. And it's written in C, like built-in functions in PHP, so it's really quite fast.

`preg_match()` is not aware of the MySQL connection character set, so it has a chance of giving a false negative -- in other words, a case where you *should* escape the string, but your test tells you not to.

As other people have pointed out, you are in the realm of pointless micro-optimization when you decide to save code or performance by testing the string. You have probably already wasted more computing resources as well as human attention by posting this question to StackOverflow than you could ever save by optimizing when you escape the strings.

Just call the escaping function and then shift your attention to converting your code to PDO, protecting your queries with parameters.

I sympathize with the size of the project to convert your code to PDO, and the difficulty in justifying the change. It's hard to convince the powers that be of the worth of the project, when it results in a vague promise of greater "security" instead of any functional change.

You could combine the effort with some other refactoring that gives some more concrete benefits, like creating a wrapper function for all queries so you can audit or profile database activity. That may convince the decision makers of the value of the project.

Comment: That's a great thought, Bill! Tying the PDO migration to another larger-scope refactoring may give the higher-ups the nudge needed to OK the change. Thanks.

Comment: Not to mention that the `mysql_*` library is deprecated and at some point will cease having support on the PHP builds which is also another point that would put your client to rest as his code would not stop functioning once they have to upgrade or their hosting given they have no power over the server their application runs on.

Comment: @Prix, yes, that's a good point, but I assume that ext/mysql will still be available, even if it's a separately-installable extension. It's inconceivable that ext/mysql will be totally gone in any future of PHP.

Comment: @BillKarwin I do agree with that but still "installable" means if per chance the system changes and it was not installed his client application goes all bad and its not all but he would have more compatibility with new systems as well as all other benefits for instance PDO the possibility of MS SQL or Oracle or MySQL besides other DBM's

Comment: @Prix, yes, no doubt PDO is a better choice, but for a big legacy app that is already written, there's no budget or schedule to rewrite the code, all environments must maintain ext/mysql. For example, every hosting company who upgrades to the hypothetical PHP "5.?" where ext/mysql has been removed will certainly install ext/mysql as well.

Comment: Yes of course but we can't say the same from 5 years now or onwards either way my previous comment was disregards the legacy app was more on a general base. For such an old application I would expect that the owner, client or person/company in charge would have their own infrastructure maintaining it, etc.

Comment: @Prix, right in a case like that they could also just never upgrade PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably found the answer in the comments. But to recap before closing this:

- security advantage: definitely not!!! As @Dagon said in the comment, apostrophes are far from being the only problem
- speed advantage: not really. Even if you manage to make any speed improvement (say by having a best-case scenario case wehre all of the variables avoid the escape function), it's still nothing compared to the DB access time.

I'd strongly suggest you to switch to prepared statements and never worry again about stuff like that.